# Extract postitions from graphviz.graphs.Digraph object created by pm4py

Tags: python, networkx, graphviz

I am trying to either extract the positions from a graphviz.graphs.Digraph object created by the pm4py package or directly translate the graphviz.graphs.Digraph object to an object that can be used in networkx and contains positions.

## Data

```
import pm4py
import pandas as pd
from pm4py.objects.conversion.log import converter as log_converter
from pm4py.visualization.dfg import visualizer as dfg_visualization

time = []
for i in range(14):
    time.append(pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01') + pd.Timedelta(days=i))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'case:concept:name': ['A','A','A','A',
                          'B','B','B','B',
                          'C','C','C',
                          'D','D','D'],
    'concept:name': ['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 5',
                     'Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 4', 'Task 5',
                     'Task 1', 'Task 3', 'Task 5',
                     'Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 5'],
    'time:timestamp': time
})

event_log = log_converter.apply(df)
dfg, _, _ = pm4py.discover_dfg(event_log)
gviz = dfg_visualization.apply(dfg, log=event_log)
```

It appears that the positional information is stored in a long number with viewing `gviz.source`, but I am not sure how to translate that into x,y coordinates to put into the `pos` attribute of a networkx.

I am looking for something like:

```
G = convert_pm4py_gviz_to_networkx_with_positions(gviz)
```

## Edit

I tried

```
parameters = {dfg_visualization.Variants.FREQUENCY.value.Parameters.FORMAT: 'dot'}
gviz = pm4py.visualization.dfg.visualizer.apply(dfg, parameters=parameters)
```

but still see the same output.

Comment: change format to "dot"

Comment: @sroush I don't see a format argument, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I did try `gviz.render(filename='gviz.dot')` to create a dot file, but I saw the same information as the `gviz.source`.

Comment: look here: https://pm4py-source.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pm4py.visualization.dfg.html

Comment: @sroush I tried adjusting the format parameter as in the edit that I made, but did not see a difference.